# Is movsbl near ret good for performance?

Tags: gcc, cpu, x86-64, micro-optimization

```
char c;
int f()
{
    return c ^ 1;
}
```

gcc compiles this into something like

```
movzbl  c(%rip), %eax
xorl    $1, %eax
movsbl  %al, %eax
ret
```

Is it useful because of some out-of-order or superscalar feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, that's a GCC missed optimization**; that C can legally be do a sign-extending load in the first place.  You should report it on the GCC bugzilla with keyword "missed-optimization".

clang, ICC, and MSVC ([on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5ILzAWmdAGpkCJsRUcAzHwAMAQTwsCSgGYQAlBwMcA7Hv1KnSoyYIBbAA5LtAEU061o7OHt4cAKzYfkq02g7OSsSYBGIsSqFxQXa%2BWQauSpgAHgSYLOgA%2BkymJcSWPvZBCarq6V4%2BWv6ckbGBBglJKcRpGb362UFSFozS4VKkLNK6c6jSAML8/ErCYhI%2BXFq0cwSLk1MA1iBaXAB0AJy0urcALFwAbAActLS3Wrbh01InnMFlIlqQVlI5oIQLpSMdQZNSHBYDBEChUF48AxMGQKBA0JjscQQMAnrYnqRTFiatCIAAjE6kOlGdQAT2kh1IBPcpQIAHkWAx2QjSFh3KxgNjGfgksgCHgAG6YaEioqYZAiEocuauTAMbWMPB04hs1YYSRSTkEYh4dzaqbMNgoDa8Q106GwFhMHkgOmoVCCAikJXEy2vW6ncGeeWoFgqgC0hWQSnjfK0KYA6kwGAwoaJxJJaA6ZsDGRDCu9XvHXk8lMBkMmntdbNdaxBcIQSHsDqQlGbCTju0W%2By6eEcThZzpctNd3rdXuEuLpK7dwt8nuFXgCgaQ7U9btddB9bO9wrdybpdLZyfMy9IoTC4ROkaiIEgCZ4sTjyJQP1/icgjrAO8l6UtSOK0gyIrMl6xDCpy3K8gKQrSpg4psFKIoyuq8pKiqYJqhqWqWjqxh6gaDBGiacFmlgBrWra9qMBKzq8PwboelAXo%2Bn6AZBiGHLhpGqDRngsYJkmKZppm2YMCm4riAgfiCGcrLMGcmDxkwCqFGuXB5jshbFlIsy3iK5aVtWtaARKSjvIeh5KO2%2BBEBo3A9n2GKfkS3ZcBYI5sbw44IpOpAIJgTBYMSljbnMdrhLodwHFwtBPLoXBnrcXBvGZYIQg%2BsLwksoUXFoM5/OEtj7Lcp5klwWVbvqUhaKW5n3k%2BIUvvAyJon%2BRI/viXn/iAeANt89BUgwNKUFBYIwWyBqIcYyHCmCYoSpha14LKuHKoyhGahanK6k1nKUcaprmvRNp2iRDosZwgUCOdnEQNxki8YGwY4oJEahSJMZxtIibJqm6bxlmObyeoqjKap6madpum0PpQj5hIdDGaZIJ5dIFZVjWLgNjEB6JbQTkdq5Q69v23mDu5Wj%2BesT3BcVU5ldcZVc9zPOxbuIAJblyztdChXPj1b7ogOuK/kNRIgAqyCeJ45QKt85S0K85SFDWYFTRBM2MvNcGLRiPLLYKq1zOtGEWltO2KntqqFOqh0GidFFUZddEkXCN1MUBrF8K6L3de9vr%2Bl9Alhn9UwA2JQNSKmhQGQWmMAtjd5SDrtbuIIitKGrB6axTLldu59CedL3ZPEzo6s5G4WRT9MVNTu8WwjjwuQkIj5FZGpUzjzw9cwCLVC%2BC7X96FTWo3aDyd1nDehSGsixiATxAA%3D%3D%3D)) compile it to the expected

```
f:
        movsbl  c(%rip), %eax           # sign extend first
        xorl    $1, %eax
        retq
```

Even trying to hand-hold GCC into that code-gen with this C fails to get GCC to do that:

```
int f() {
    int tmp = c;
    tmp ^= 1;
    return tmp;
}
```

---

I'm guessing that maybe GCC decides to just load 1 byte and sign-extend *after* instead of before.  IDK why it thinks that would be a good idea.  But anyway, some kind of extension to 32-bit is necessary to avoid a false dependency on the old value of RAX.

Writing the C that way tricks ICC into this missed optimization, but not MSVC or clang.  They still optimize this to sign-extending first, because they know that XOR can't change any high bits.

```
int extend_after() {
    char tmp = c^1;
    return tmp;
}
```

now ICC is like GCC, but for some reason sign-extends all the way to 64-bit:

```
extend_after:
        movzbl    c(%rip), %eax                                 #10.16
        xorl      $1, %eax                                      #10.18
        movsbq    %al, %rax                                     #11.12
        ret                                                     #11.12
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe gcc misses such a simple optimization. It's even harder to believe that icc makes similar mistakes.

Comment: @ntysdd: Compilers miss apparently-simple optimizations all the time, but yes this one was a bit surprising for gcc.  If you've looked at ICC's code-gen much, you wouldn't be surprised about it, though!  It's very good at auto-vectorization, but often not great at squeezing all the instructions out of code.